# Collapsing DIVs with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with two divs on it. This page looks like the following:

```
<div id="waitDiv">
  <div id="waitText">Analyzing...</div>
  <img src="wait.gif" />
</div>

<div id="finishedDiv" style="visibility:collapse;">
  <div>You may now proceed</div>
  <div>Please remember that....</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var progressTimer = setTimeout("updateState()", 5000);
  });

  var count = 1;
  function updateState() {
    if (count <= 5) {
      var progressTimer = setTimeout("updateState()", 5000);
      count = count + 1;
    }
    else {
      $("#waitDiv").css("visibility", "collapse");
      $("#finishedDiv").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Basically, when the page loads, I need it to wait for a bit of time. Then, I need to show the information in the finishedDiv when the time has elapsed. Currently, the finishedDiv does show. However, it shows below the waitDiv. The waitDiv goes invisible. But, I need the finishedDiv to be positioned where the waitDiv was. Why does the finishedDiv appear below the waitDiv even though I collapse it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `visibility: collapse;` you should use `display: none` in this case, so it takes up no space in the page.

Some other suggestions: don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, pass the function and you can use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for that `display: none` I was talking about, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var progressTimer = setTimeout(updateState, 5000);
});

var count = 1;
function updateState() {
  if (count <= 5) {
    var progressTimer = setTimeout(updateState, 5000);
    count = count + 1;
  }
  else {
    $("#waitDiv").hide();     //display: none;
    $("#finishedDiv").show(); //restore display, in this case display: block;
  }
}
```

Just also change the `#finishedDiv` to be hidden the same way initially, like this:

```
<div id="finishedDiv" style="display: none;">
```

Instead of [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) you could also use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for example, to add a bit of flair if you wanted.

Comment: It might be better to use JQuery to hide the `finishedDiv` when the page loads, and then show it after the predetermined time. Otherwise, those without Javascript will never see the DIVs content. Remember that screen readers usually ignore content that is set to `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

The collapse [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp) applies to only to table elements, so it's really up to the browser as to how to show a collapsed div.  You should try setting display to none and see if that achieves the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"display:none"` as the initial style for finishedDiv, so it is not even put into the layout of the page. Then you can simply use `toggle()` to make it visible:

Unrelated, you can avoid use of `eval(...)` by specifying the name of the function to be called by `setTimeout(...)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var progressTimer = setTimeout(updateState, 5000);
});

var count = 1;
function updateState() {
  if (count <= 5) {
    var progressTimer = setTimeout(updateState, 5000);
    count = count + 1;
  }
  else {
    $("#waitDiv").toggle();
    $("#finishedDiv").toggle();
  }
}
```

​